# Voice dictation (speech recognition) aborted/stopped after reloadData call on collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, voice

I have a textfield in my app. There is a  method that listens for changes in textView.

```
- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    //Some code that imports data from textView to collection view
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

When typing in textView, it works just perfectly. But when I press voice dictation button and start dictating, the dictation aborts after first chunk of voice becomes text. In other words, after `- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` and  `[self.collectionView reloadData];` inside of it is called.

I have checked abortion is caused directly by `[self.collectionView reloadData];` . If I comment this line, I can dictate as much as I can. But if it is called, the voice dictation is just aborted and you have to press dictation button again.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve abortion problem?

In response to: @nikolay-shmyrev:
Thank you for the comment.
I am using `JSQMessagesViewController`
I just added the line

```
self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.delegate = self;
```

and method:

```
- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

to `viewDidLoad` method in `DemoMessagesViewController.m` to illustrate the problem. (the example with my issue can be checked https://github.com/Marindrew/JSQMessagesViewController , when you launch the app, open JSQMessagesViewController through storyboard and start voice dictation using keyboard. It stops after the first word)

Comment: You need to explain more the relation between textView and collectionView in your code or try to create [minimal self-contained example](http://sscce.org). It looks like textView is inside or somehow related to the collection view or collection view has some elements that are harmful. It is not clear what are you doing without rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you, Nikolay, I updated the question.

Comment: Ok, great, though it does not seem like "minimal" example ;) From the code I see that text view is part of collectionView and by reloading the collectionView you just destroy text view. Are you really sure you want that behavior at all? Maybe you can implement required changes in more straightforward way.

Comment: Hm, I checked thoroughly and I cannot find why text view is part of collection view. There is separate `JSQMessagesCollectionView *collectionView;` property and `@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) JSQMessagesInputToolbar *inputToolbar;` in `JSQMessagesViewController`. I also put a breakpoint before I call reloadData and checked that there is no `textView` or `JSQMessagesInputToolbar` inside of that collection view before update. How have you found that it is a part of collectionView? Thank you.